# Remove unnecessary brackets in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I wrote a code to parse data in php as follows:

```
<?php
$db_name="hotels";
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db_name);


if(! $conn ) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
} 
else{
    //echo"<h3>Database cannection established</h3>";
}

$sql_query_for_username = "select distinct `username` from hotels.ratingoffooditem";
$usernames_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query_for_username);

$users = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($usernames_result)){
    array_push($users, $row["username"]);
}

//print_r($users);
$response=array();
foreach($users as $user){
    $sql_query= "select `food item`,rating from hotels.ratingoffooditem where username='$user'";

    $result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query);
    $abc = array();
    if($result !=false){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $def = array($row["food item"]=>$row['rating']);
            //echo (json_encode($def));
            //echo "</br>";
            array_push($abc,$def);

        }

   }
      //echo "</br>";
            //print_r(json_encode($abc));
            //echo "</br>";
        array_push($response, array("$user"=>array($abc))); 
   //echo "</br>";
}

echo json_encode($response);
//echo "</br>";echo "</br>";echo "</br>";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I would like to get result like:

{"Shree":{"Chiken-Momo":4,"Buff-Momo":3,"Chicken-Thukpa":3,"Chiken Momo":4,"Buff Chowmein":2.5,"Veg-Chowmein":3.5},"Juppi":{"Samosa":4},"lil":{"Chiken-Momo":1},"bidur":{"Chiken-Momo":4.5}}

But, I got this:

[{"Shree":[[{"pizza":"3"},{"Burger":"3.5"},{"Chiken-Momo":"4.5"},{"Chiken Momo":"4"},{"Chiken Momo":"4"},{"Chiken-Momo":"4"},{"Veg-Chowmien":"2"},{"Buff-Momo":"3"},{"Chiken-Thukpa":"4"},{"Chiken-Thukpa":"4"},{"Chiken-Thukpa":"2"}]]},{"Juppi":[[{"Samosa":"4"},{"Chiken-Momo":"4"}]]},{"lil":[[{"Chiken-Momo":"1"}]]},{"bnabin51":[[{"Chiken-Momo":"4.5"}]]},{"bidur":[[{"Chiken-Momo":"4.5"}]]}]

**Now how can i remove the unnecessary brackets?**

Comment: those are not unnecessary brackets. you are generating json like this. those are array in json object. you can use `json_encode($foo, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)` to get only json objects.

Comment: check your json using json validator, unformated

Comment: `array_push($response, array("$user"=>$abc));` use this instead of `array_push($response, array("$user"=>array($abc))); ` because `$abc` is already an array so there is no need to use `array($abc)`

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got this  simply as follows:

```
$response=array();
foreach($users as $user){
    $sql_query= "select `food item`,rating from hotels.ratingoffooditem where username='$user'";

    $result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query);
    $abc = array();
    if($result !=false){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $abc[$row['food item']]=$row['rating'];

        }

    }

    $response[$user]=$abc;

}
```